# "... Much was" vs "... much was a"

Tags: phrases, phrase-usage

I was writing something in Google Docs, and it flagged one of my sentences. The context in question was this (summarized):

> Much of the area was [this] district.

The correction/suggestion was this:

> Much of the area was a [this] district.

I may just be doubting myself in this circumstance, but I'm thinking my own sentence is correct. Is my sentence correct?

Comment: Is 'this' the name of the district or a reference to the kind of landscape?

Comment: Name of a district.

Comment: Then the grammar-checker is definitely wrong (as they sometimes are). You don't need an article before a geographical name.

Comment: Something is missing in "Much of the area was Chelsea district." Maybe "Much of the area was the Chelsea district," "Much of the area was a red-light district," or "Much of the area was considered Chelsea district."

Comment: In your example of "Much of the area was a red-light district", is "a" mandatory? If it's not a proper name, I'm not sure if "a" would be required. If you replaced "red-light" with "farmland", adding that "a" seems off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sentence parsers, including Google's, don't have perfect dictionaries. When faced with a word it does not known, the parser will guess at the word's part of speech. I suspect in this case the parser interpreted the word represented by *[this]* as an adjective, not a proper name.

The following without the article is correct for a proper name:

> Much of the area was Chelsea district.

And the following with the article is correct for an adjective:

> Much of the area was a seedy district.

If you capitalize the real word represented above as *[this]*, you may get the opposite advice from the grammar checker.

Comment: The second example also includes the aforementioned "red-light" and "farmland" examples?